# Ubuntu Phone - screen mirroring

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'd like to know if there is something, any app to do screen mirroring on my connected TV ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you looking to do this over LAN/wifi?

Comment: Or over a cable to a TV input?

Comment: Because some phones have a mini (or micro) HDMI output on them already.

Comment: This may help you also: http://www.j5create.com/our-products/android/juc600.html

Comment: Thank you Daniel ! But I'd like to use the mirroring with Wi-fi because I don't have micro HDMI on my MX4.

Comment: Easiest way to do that is probably something like run a VNC server on your phone.